# Display the difference between two JS objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display the name of property where their values are difference.
Then, I'm trying to display the property which is not present on the other variable

```js
myObj1 = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": "45",
  "car": 20,
  "test": 30,
  "example": 20
};
myObj2 = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": "30",
  "car": 10,
  "example": 10
};

// or 

//myObj1 = { "name":"John", "age":"45", "car":20 };
//myObj2 = { "name":"John", "age":"30", "car":10,"test":30 };



// find keys
keyObj1 = Object.keys(myObj1);
keyObj2 = Object.keys(myObj2);

// find values
valueObj1 = Object.values(myObj1);
valueObj2 = Object.values(myObj2);

// find max length to iterate 
if (keyObj1.length > keyObj2.length) {
  var biggestKey = keyObj1.length;
} else {
  var biggestKey = keyObj2.length;
}

// now compare their keys and values 
for (var i = 0; i < biggestKey; i++) {
  //console.log(biggestKey)
  if (keyObj1[i] == keyObj2[i] && valueObj1[i] !== valueObj2[i]) {
    console.log('property:' + keyObj1[i]);
    console.log('first:' + valueObj1[i]);
    console.log('second:' + valueObj2[i]);
  }
}
```

Actual result:

- property: age, 45,30
- property: car,20,10
- property: test,30,10
- property: example,20,undefined

Expected result:

- property: age, 45,30
- property: car,20,10
- property: test,30,undefined
- property: example,20,10

Comment: note: you're not dealing with JSON in the code you posted ... they are just *objects*

Comment: Do you mean `property` instead of `project`?

Comment: Yes property sorry

Comment: Are the objects always going to be 1 level deep? (should it also handle `{other: {name: ""}, foo: "bar"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problems**

- biggestKey is a length instead of array
- compare object by key in biggestKey

```js
myObj1 = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": "45",
  "car": 20,
  "test": 30,
  "example": 20
};
myObj2 = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": "30",
  "car": 10,
  "example": 10
};


// find keys
keyObj1 = Object.keys(myObj1);
keyObj2 = Object.keys(myObj2);

// find max length to iterate 
if (keyObj1.length > keyObj2.length) {
  var biggestKey = keyObj1;
} else {
  var biggestKey = keyObj2;
}

// now compare their keys and values 
for (var i = 0; i < biggestKey.length; i++) {
  //console.log(biggestKey)
  var key = biggestKey[i];
  if (myObj1[key] != myObj2[key]) {
    console.log('project:', key, myObj1[key], myObj2[key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it work but if you add another property ("example" : 20 in myOb1 and "example": 10 in myOb2) and then I want display the value of property by using varObj1 and varObj2, I've got test 30 10

Comment: Indeed, need to attribute every property with the same

Comment: @tatatiti after reading your comments several times. I don't get what you are trying to say. sorry.  where does varObj1 or varObj2 comes from?

Comment: Yes sorry, if we add another property like "example" in myObj1 and myObj2. Then i'm doing console.log('first': valueOb1(i))  and console.log('second': valueOb2(i)). My output is {...} project:example, first: 20, second: undefined and must be project:example, first: 20, second: 10

Comment: @tatatiti updated.  no need of valueOb1 and valueOb2 use myObj1[key] instead

Comment: My bad, need to use MyObj[key] and not valueObj(i)

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to iterate through both objects and to ignore the properties that exist in both objects in the second loop.

```js
var myObj1 = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": "45",
  "car": 20,
  "test": 30,
  "example": 20
};
var myObj2 = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": "30",
  "car": 10,
  "example": 10
};

for (var key in myObj1) {
  if (myObj1[key] !== myObj2[key]) console.log("property:", key, myObj1[key], myObj2[key]);
}


for (key in myObj2) {
  if (!(key in myObj2)) { // ignore if key exists in myObj1 (if it exists, then it got checked in the previous loop)
    if (myObj1[key] !== myObj2[key]) console.log("property:", key, myObj1[key], myObj2[key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes sure, but another answer it's more like what I'm trying to do

Comment: @tatatiti Why? Both answers produce the same result and this one is shorter. What is it, that you are trying to do? Also using `for...in` retrieves all the iteratable properties (including inherited ones), whereas `Object.keys` does not.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you

```
function getDifference(compareObject, baseObject) {
    function difference(compareObject, baseObject) {
        return _.transform(compareObject, function(results, value, key) {
            if (!_.isEqual(value, baseObject[key])) {
                results[key] = (_.isObject(value) && _.isObject(baseObject[key])) ? changes(value, baseObject[key]) : value;
            }
        });
    }
    return difference(compareObject, baseObject);
}
```

Comment: `_` is not defined anywhere, also why have wrapped `difference` with another function only to call it using the same arguments again?